# UITextField in UITableViewCell using imageView of cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, uitextfield

I created a custom UITableViewCell with textfield, but I would like to use the imageview of cell, instead insert one in my custom cell.

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class TextFieldTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField : UITextField!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

This is the xib

[image: xib]

In View Controller:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell : TextFieldTableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "textFieldCell", for: indexPath) as! TextFieldTableViewCell

            cell!.textField.text = "William Stevenson"
            cell!.textField.tag = indexPath.row
            cell!.imageView?.image = UIImage.init(icon: .FAUser, size: CGSize(width: 35, height: 35), textColor : UIColor.gray)

            return cell
        }
}
```

But the textfield goes under the picture

[image: first]

I try insert imageView in my custom cell

[image: xib 2]

but the first separator line has a different width

[image]

How can I fix the problem? 
Thank you!

Comment: Do you want separator line like first one? or the second one?

Comment: like the second one

Comment: Please don't append _solved_ to the title. Instead consider marking an answer as accepted. That will tell others the question has been solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using my imageview ad set "Separator", in IB of my xib, with "Custom insets" left value equals to 65.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for having separator lines with *two different widths* is, when you put imageView outside of custom cell initially, it's on top of the image has covered the separator line. When you put imageview inside the separator is visible. Looks like images are having white background so that they are masking separator line. If my guess is correct, please check your icons background. If it's white in colour change them to transparent. Otherwise give some padding between imageview and cell bottom

Comment: The icon background is **UIColor.clear**. I want the separator line like the second one (the shorter one)

Comment: I don't know exact problem until I see the code. But I can tell you a hack. In the first picture, you are getting text field under the picture right. So keep like that only and for the text field left-to-margin constraint change by adding icon width to existing width of the constraint.

Comment: How much is the constraint to align Texfield's text with the text of the second line (the second row is a normal UITableViewCell)? How do I decrease the width of the first separator line to make it like the second? The problem is the with of separator line, not the textField below the image.

Comment: in the first case I have only textfield in custom cell, and I use the imageView of cell : cell!.imageView?.image = UIImage.init(icon: .FAUser, size: CGSize(width: 35, height: 35), textColor : UIColor.gray), but I don't know how much the left constraint of the textField should be to align it. In the second case, I use imageview in xib but the separator line is long.

Comment: align left constraint to the width of the icon., ie, 35 as in your case

Comment: The solution you propose is for the second case, but it is not what I want, because the separator line is long.